# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] numpy-1.20.1.dist-infor \\METADATA

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, metadata

I wanna install three packages in anaconda, but I face the following error.

`Error: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2]  No such file or directory: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy-1.20.1.dist-info\\METADATA'`.

I have changed `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem@LongPathsEnabled` to `1`, but it does not still work. There are some similar problems with `pip` and some solutions are provided but I could not apply them. Is there any difference between the `pip\\METADA` error and `numpy\\METADATA` error?

I have basic knowledge and I would be thankful if someone can explain how to fix it with details. For example, some people suggested installing in another directory, but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: I should add that I cannot even upgrade pip because of numpy error. Also, I used the command pip install -U numpy, but I face the same error.

Answer (score 7):

Check if you have any other `.\numpy-1.20.*xxx*.dist-info` folders.
If you do have and it is not empty ( it should have METADATA in it as well) copy that folder content to your

```
\numpy-1.20.1.dist-info\
```

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the folder of "numpy-1.20.1.dist-info" in error information firstly, and try install again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).